# How to make a multiple dictionary into one dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to make a dictionary with the title of a content section and the link related to it (on a page of khan academy).

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming#intro-to-programming')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

#find course steps links
courses_links = soup.find_all(class_='link_1uvuyao-o_O-nodeStyle_cu2reh-o_O-nodeStyleIcon_4udnki')

list_courses={}
#print(courses_links)

for links in courses_links:
    courses = links.extract()
    link_course = courses['href']
    #print(link_course)
    title_course= links.find(class_='nodeTitle_145jbuf')
    #print(title_course)
    span_title_course=title_course.span
    #print(span_title_course)
    text_span=span_title_course.text.strip()
    #print(text_span)
    final_link_course ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+link_course
    #print(final_link_course)
    list_courses[text_span]=final_link_course
    print(list_courses) #showing weird things
```

I would like to get something like `{title1 : link1, title2: link2...}`. But instead I get a multiple dictionaries (with multiple `{}`).

Comment: You're printing `list_courses` in every iteration of the loop, so every time you add an entry it prints the entire `dict` again.

Comment: you actually already have a dictionary of the desired format (`{title1 : link1, title2: link2...}`. As @cody mentioned you simply print `list_courses` dictionary in every iteration.

Comment: just print  `print(list_courses)` outside for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use pandas which very good data analysis tool for python programming.
Just need to install `pandas` using `pip`

import pandas as pd

Pass your dictionary like below.

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list_courses,orient='index')
print(df)
```

It is just an another options.Please don't take it otherwise.